# convert a string of int separated by a dot into a string of char

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to convert a string (eg: 0.1.2) into a string of char (so it becomes: abc).

Where is the bug?

```js
let alphacode = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27];
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function uncrypt(stringToUncrypt) {
    let temp = new Array();
    temp = stringToUncrypt.split(".");
    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        //console.log('Questa è la stringa senza il PUNTO: ' + temp[i]);
    }

    //console.log('contenuto di temp: ' + temp);
    let result = [];
    //console.log('contenuto di result: ' + result);

    for (let j in temp) {
        //console.log('siamo dentro let j in temp:' + temp[j]);
        for (let x in alphacode) {
            //console.log('siamo dentro let x in alphacode:' + alphacode[x]);
            for (let z in alphabet) {
                if (temp[j] === alphacode[x]) {
                    alphacode[x] = alphabet[z];
                    console.log('contenuto di alphabet [z]' + alphabet[z]);
                    result += alphabet[z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('----------UNCRYPTED----------')
    return 'Risultato: ' + result;
}

let text = uncrypt('0.1');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Does alphacode consist of numbers/integers only? Because you declared them as strings......on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've stated in your code `result` is an array you need to [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the answer into it rather than concatenate to it like a string:

```
result.push(alphabet[z]);
```

Then, to get a string returned from the function with the correct formatting, you should use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
return 'Risultato: ' + result.join('');
```

You are using far too many loops in your code, however. You only need one:

```js
let alphacode = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27'];
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function uncrypt(stringToUncrypt) {
  let temp = stringToUncrypt.split(".");
  let result = [];

  // loop over the split string ONLY
  for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

    // Get in the index of the current element in the
    // alphacode array
    const index = alphacode.indexOf(temp[i]);

    // Push the corresponding element with that index from
    // alphabet into the result array
    result.push(alphabet[index]);
  }
  return 'Risultato: ' + result.join('');
}

let text = uncrypt('0.1');
console.log(text); // ab
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nbwexdup/1/)

Answer (score 2):

With just small modifications to your code. You are overcomplicating it.

```
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function uncrypt(stringToUncrypt) {
    const temp = stringToUncrypt.split("."); // no need to initialize the variable to an empty array, just set it to the splitted string directly
    let result = ''; // as you want a string as output, it makes sense to directly work with strings here
    for (let j of temp) { // use for..of to iterate over the characters inside the array, e.g. "0", "1"
        result += alphabet[parseInt(j)]; // take the char as a position in the alphabet, e.g. alphabet[0] -> "a"
    }
    console.log('----------UNCRYPTED----------')
    return 'Risultato: ' + result;
}

let text = uncrypt('0.1');
console.log(text);
```

In my solution, numbers stored in `temp` correspond to indexes of the `alphabet` array.

Comment: `for..in` only works for strings where the index ewuals the char, so `0.1` works by accident, `0.2.1` would not. `for..of` is what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let alphacode = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27'];
    let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    function uncrypt(decodedString) {
        const chars = decodedString.split(".");
        return chars.map(char => alphabet[alphacode.indexOf(char)]).join("");
        
    }

    let text = uncrypt('0.1');
    console.log('Risultato: ' + text);
```

`map` helps loop through the array and replace and return the current value with the matching code in your `alphacode`.

Comment: Could someone at least explain the down votes? Thanks.

Comment: Mad cuz bad  .

Answer (score -2):

```
function uncrypt(stringToUncrypt) {
  let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

   return stringToUncrypt.split(".").map(i => alphabet[i-1]).join('');
}
```

short way of doing what you want

Comment: Could be, but Andrea asked for string replacement. Imagine the numbers as strings, not numbers.

Comment: yeah it replaces string of numbers to string of chars, what's wrong?

Comment: I's a really bad answer. Not only do you not answer the question, you don't give any explanation of what these new functions are.

Comment: @Andy I think it's quite simple and not need to explanation

Comment: Nothing wrong. But has to be known. Because `alphacode` is an array of strings.
What if the numbers are changed to other crypt chars?

Comment: @Matthi I didn't get what you mean, this function only for strings with numbers

Comment: `1 ≠ '1'` `alphacode` is an array of strings, not of numbers!

Comment: but where you have seen array of numbers?

Comment: In your `map` function you expect i to be a number/integer, but it is not. It is a string like `'1'`

Comment: it doesn't disturb in this case, because this function created for string with numbers, if in strings can be chars too, in question should been mentioned about that